# Android HTC Desire Voice input issues

Tags: voice-recognition, android

Would anyone have an idea as to why an app would work on almost every phone that has 2.1 but not the Desire?

One of my apps uses voice input and the Desire is the only phone that force closes when the voice prompt comes up.

The worst part is that I don't know how to test this, I don't have one or know anyone who does.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I finally found out that HTC disabled voice in the Desire and you have to do a work around to install it.

So if you are relying on voice input make sure you use the code in the google example to catch the error:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
     List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
             new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
     if (activities.size() == 0) {           
         noResults.setText("Voice input not found on this phone.");
     }else{
            //If voice is enabled
            }
```

Comment: ask someone who has your app installed, that should send the log output from his phone. For this he can download a free app from Market called Log Collector.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing to do first is to get the exception report. Since you can't test it by yourself, I would use a tool to get the exception report from your customers. In Android 2.2 the built-in tool can be used. If you have other targeting SDKs I would recommend this services: http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/ to get a remote stacktrace.

Then if you post the stacktrace here, I think somebody will be able to help you!